# How to list out Top 10 salaries with out using TOP

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can i display Top 10 salaries from a table with out using TOP

Comment: StackOverflow: Doing your homework for you since 2008!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  Salary
from
(
  SELECT  Salary, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY SALARY desc) AS 'Salaries'
FROM User2
)#emp 
  WHERE  Salaries <=10 order by salary desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER OVER ( order by ... )`

```
SELECT t.sal from
(
  SELECT  sal, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY sal desc) AS rownum
  FROM table
) t 
WHERE  t.rownum <= 10
```